# how to use css and <li> to make a 1 to 50 pixel square with no border

Tags: html, css, pie-chart

I'd like to use different sized squares from a  to make pie shapes, but I'm having trouble with the css to make a square one pixel in height and width with no borders.  Here is my current css

```
#q-graph {position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;  margin: 1.1em 0 3.5em; padding: 0;  background: #DDD;  border: 2px solid gray; list-style: none;  font: 9px Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;}
#q-graph ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#q-graph li {position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 150px; z-index: 2;  margin: 0; padding: 0;  text-align: center; list-style: none;}
#q-graph li.bar {position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; border: none }
#q-graph li.bar p {margin: 5px 0 0; padding: 0;}
```

and here is a bit of the pie slice

```
<ul id="q-graph">

<a href='blah.com'><li class='bar' style='left:2px; top:126px; width:37px; height:37px; background:blue;border-color:blue;'></li></a>
<a href='blah.com'><li class='bar' style='left:9px; top:164px; width:37px; height:37px; background:blue;border-color:blue;'></li></a>
```

I'd like help with this as my CSS skills seem to be inadequate for the task.

[This is what it looks like at the moment](http://users.tpg.com.au/rowead/pie.html)

Comment: I don't see how the above code would produce a pie chart. Maybe you need a Javascript library like raphael instead. http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: plus, placing anchor tags in lists is invalid markup (and the page layout will be... strange)

Comment: Can't use any javascript or go out side our internal network to things like google resources.

Comment: Well than its *really* impossible. If you can maybe create your pie chart graphically, and load it statically from the server using the `img` tag, or generate it from the server-side

Comment: I gave up and used JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to your question would probably be 
"Remove the 'width:37px; height:37px;' from your inline css."

Comment: However, i don't fully believe in success of your idea.